# Trying to implement MGSwipeTableCell in an iOS table view

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer, uitableview

I'm trying to implement a swipeable table view in my Swift 2, Xcode 7 project.

I want to use this library:

https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell

I am just trying to figure out the right way to implement this into my project.

I have a UIView with a TableView within it as well as a custom TableViewCell

Here is the implementation code per the GitHub repo:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
let reuseIdentifier = "programmaticCell"
var cell = self.table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier) as! MGSwipeTableCell!
if cell == nil
{
  cell = MGSwipeTableCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}

cell.textLabel!.text = "Title"
cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "Detail text"
cell.delegate = self //optional

//configure left buttons
cell.leftButtons = [MGSwipeButton(title: "", icon: UIImage(named:"check.png"), backgroundColor: UIColor.greenColor())
  ,MGSwipeButton(title: "", icon: UIImage(named:"fav.png"), backgroundColor: UIColor.blueColor())]
cell.leftSwipeSettings.transition = MGSwipeTransition.Rotate3D

//configure right buttons
cell.rightButtons = [MGSwipeButton(title: "Delete", backgroundColor: UIColor.redColor())
  ,MGSwipeButton(title: "More",backgroundColor: UIColor.lightGrayColor())]
cell.rightSwipeSettings.transition = MGSwipeTransition.Rotate3D

return cell
}
```

Here is the cellForRowAtIndexPath func in my current project:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let post = posts[indexPath.row]

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostCell") as? PostCell {

        cell.request?.cancel()

        var img: UIImage?

        if let url = post.imageUrl {
            img = FeedVCViewController.imageCache.objectForKey(url) as? UIImage
        }

        cell.configureCell(post, img: img)

        return cell
    } else {
        return PostCell()
    }
}
```

I also need to implement this callback:

```
MGSwipeButton(title: "Delete", backgroundColor: UIColor.redColor(), callback: {
  (sender: MGSwipeTableCell!) -> Bool in
  println("Convenience callback for swipe buttons!")
  return true
})
```

Can anyone guide me in the right direction on how to do this? I'm just trying to save myself a lot of headache as I am new to mobile development.

I'm mostly confused on the "cell" declaration and "if" statement in the implementation code and how to combine it with the custom cell I've created.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should make `PostCell` a subclass of `MGSwipeTableCell`, if you haven't already. I assume you're asking about `var cell =…; if cell == nil`. This is an alternative, less swifty, way of saying `if let cell =…` However the if and else blocks are reversed.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more? I do have `PostCell` as a subclass of `MGSwipeTableCell`. And yes, I am asking about `var cell =…; if cell == nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostCell")` is the same as saying

```
if  tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostCell") != nil { 
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostCell")
   }
```

They are doing something similar by declaring a variable setting it equal to an optional. They check if the optional is nil. If so, they initialize a new object and set cell equal to that, so they can safely unwrap.

If PostCell is a subclass of MGSwipeTableCell you can add leftButtons and rightButtons just like they do. e.g.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let post = posts[indexPath.row]

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostCell") as? PostCell {
    cell.request?.cancel()

    var img: UIImage?

    if let url = post.imageUrl {
        img = FeedVCViewController.imageCache.objectForKey(url) as? UIImage
    }

    cell.configureCell(post, img: img)



     cell.rightButtons = [MGSwipeButton(title: "Delete", backgroundColor: UIColor.redColor(), callback: {
      (sender: MGSwipeTableCell!) -> Bool in
      print("Convenience callback for delete button!")
      return true
    })
        ,MGSwipeButton(title: "More",backgroundColor: UIColor.lightGrayColor(),callback: {
      (sender: MGSwipeTableCell!) -> Bool in
      print("Convenience callback for more button!")
      return true
    })]

    return cell
    } else {
        return PostCell()
    }
}
```